# Is accepting an offer from my previous organization for a lower role than that of my previous one a good choice?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, resignation, employer, demotion

It has been 5 months since I have joined this company as a data manager, however, within this small duration, there have been many ups and downs. Listing a few

1. In some of our reports, the figures reported are simply incorrect. There are double-counting of some transactions. We over-report around 15% to 20% of the completed volume. There is an audit coming in next month.
2. The previous manager (before me) was terminated due to reasons similar to above. People say even though it was not entirely his fault he was made a scapegoat.
3. My manager (Asst. Dir.) ask me to sign on each and every report before it is rolled out. The sign off should be on email and with clear words that I've verified the numbers and the report is correct.
4. I find my manager not supportive at all, no vision, no guidance, no clear requirement. He simply yells at anything.
5. Consequences - getting health issues, I do not get sufficient sleep, get angry towards my family, losing confidence in my abilities.

With all those problems, I called up my prior company boss. I had worked there for seven years as a manager, but as an individual contributor.

Within a couple of weeks he sent me an offer letter but for a lower level with no change in salary - i.e. the salary is not reduced but the position. I inquired about the position to which he said - you first join, we will try to work out on the position.

I put down my resignation letter here and they are offering me to stay back. Asked me to not sign off any future report.

I'm a bit concerned with regards to my future career path - Should I accept the offer at a lower position or should I stay back as manager and continue the suffer until I get an opportunity of better/similar position?

Comment: Why would you not accept it? Do you have any better options?

Comment: If your current job is bad because it's a bad company / bad manager scenario, why would it be different if you stay on. You already decided to resign and have an offer with the same salary that you had before - why would you not accept it? You haven't written anything about why you left that job, so you may want to consider what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question title a bit to improve it, feel free to revert if you feel otherwise.

Comment: Thank you all offer accepted from the previous company!!!

Answer (score 2):

You worked somewhere for 7 years without any of the management inflicted problems you now face. They have made you an offer seemingly without taking financial advantage of your situation, and stated that they will review your role later.

It sounds like they really want you back and have found a workable solution.

Grab the offer with both hands, but have a week or so off between job changes to get the stress out of your system.

Good luck, and it sounds like things are looking up for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

**We can't answer this for it, it's ultimately up to you to decide.**

But we can offer advice and help you to ask yourself the right questions.

- Why did you leave your old job?
- What are your chances of finding a new job?
- Did you like your old company?

If you liked your old company, my guess was that you moved for a raise?

You said the new job doesn't have a reduced salary, just a demotion - it sounds pretty good of them to offer this to you! It sounds like they want to ensure you're serious about staying on there before they give you back a bunch of responsibility.

The way I see it, if you chances of finding a new job at your current position aren't super high (as in you won't in the next 2-3 months) quit and go back because otherwise you're hurting your mental health.

Do be aware that he's offering a lifeline and that if you quit again, you're likely to have burnt that bridge and looks pretty fickle on your CV.

Whatever you decide to do, quitting your current job *soon* sounds like the best thing for you.

Comment: Thank you, Bee! why did I leave my previous job? Frankly speaking, it was because I was offered a team handling role. My old boss was ready to give me a salary match then and there. I think life had different choices for me. Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: @Vasim then go back! Work your way up and get that team leadership role in your old company. That's my advice. Talk to your boss about taking some courses to better equipt you for the role you want maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot make decisions for you, but if I were in your shoes, I would not think twice to resign and accept the offer from the previous company. The way I see it:

- There is no *future* for you in your current company.
- You need to search for a new job and move out as soon as possible, and in current scenario, you already have one offer from your previous company.
- It's not sure whether there was an interview conducted for the latest offer you received:

  - If it was offered to you without an interview process and based on your past records - it seems the company still values you - I'd be delighted to work for an organisation and boss like that.
  - If it was offered after the regular interview process - that means you proved your worth to the organization (once again).
- Also, your previous organization is seemingly willing to negotiate the contracts further (in your favor) once you join - that's one more indication that they want to have you back on-board.

All in all, you need to move out of your current organization, which has a very toxic work culture. Accepting the offer extended to you seems to be the quickest way out of this mess. That said this is my personal opinion - your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank Sourav, the offer letter was without an interview. It was all because of the 7-year relation that I had with the company and boss. Even though it is your personal opinion I wanted to know what does a community think. Cheers!